# How can I create a cell or formula that will auto insert hyphens

Tags: excel

I am looking to take device serial numbers that my vendor sends my team and have the spreadsheet insert the Hyphans automatically. They arrive like this xx0x1x2x1x23x123x1x1 and I would like for my team to copy them from the email and paste them into the spreadsheet so it reads in this format xx-0x1x2x-1x23x-123-x1x1.

I cannot use a macros or VBS scripts because this is on a shared O365 online workbook and most users have the Microsoft 365 Business Basic license. Also the standard formatting will not work being that the serial number is alphanumeric. I have tried some CONCATENATE, TEXTJOIN options, but have not been able to get it to work with more than 3 hyphans. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REDUCE(LAMBDA()) to do REPLACE to insert the `-` where needed:

```
=REDUCE(A1,{17,14,9,3},LAMBDA(a,b,REPLACE(a,b,0,"-")))
```

**NOTES**

1. This assumes that the placement in the string is fixed.
2. The Array {17,14,9,3} is the relative index of each `-` compared to the original individually.

[image]